# How to get Product item count in layered navigation on advanced search result page?

Tags: magento

Actually I want display product attributes item count on product list page but when I call

```
&lt;block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav"  template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"&gt;
```

`XML` block in advanced search result page in `catalogsearch.xml` I got wrong item count on left side. Please suggest me how to get proper count of attributes?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can load category model using categoryId and then call getProductCount function like this:

```
$categoryData = Mage::getModel('catelog/category')->load($categoryId)->getProductCount();

    echo $categoryData;
```

This shall print your product count in this particular category. You can use block or your template to run your code, or in run-time you may also use your controller using an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

Open **catalogsearch.xml** from your theme's layout directory.

Search the keyword **catalogsearch_advanced_result**

Set below code between opening and closing tag of catalogsearch_advanced_result

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```